# Getting iframe height on safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm trying to use jQuery to dynamically resize an iframe. The code works on Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't on Safari.

There isn't much online I can find about it, but I did find some posts describing to use jQuery(window).load() to make height work, but it hasn't been working for me.

Here's the original code:

```
<iframe id="dbframe" src="https://transitiontn.org/assessment-database-vr/" width="100%" scrolling="no" >
```

```
<script>
  jQuery("#dbframe").on("load", function() {
  let head = jQuery(this).contents().find("head");
  let css = '<style>#top-header, #main-header, #main-footer{display: none;}#page-container{padding-top: 0!important;}               </style>';
  jQuery(head).append(css);
  let bdyheight = jQuery(this).contents().find("body").height();
  jQuery(this).height(bdyheight);

  let dblinks = jQuery(this).contents().find("td a");
  jQuery(dblinks).click(function() {
    jQuery("html").animate({scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
    window.setTimeout(function(){jQuery("#dbframe").height(2000)}, 2000);   
  });  
  }); 
</script>
```

When I run it on Safari with debugging it sets bdyheight to 0. I tried wrapping all of this in a  jQuery(window).load() function and a JQuery("dbframe").load() function but both seemed to stop the on("load") function from firing at all. Any thoughts would be appreciated! Thank you very much!